# Convergence to matrix in QR algorithm

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Studying proof of $QR$ algorithm for finding eigenvalues, I was faced with fact: $\Sigma^k L \Sigma^{-k} \rightarrow L^{'}$, where $L^{'} = {\rm diag}(L)$, $L$ is lower triangle matrix, $\Sigma$ - diagonal matrix.

I have no idea, how to prove this fact, and I want some intuition behind the formal proof.

I must add that matrix $\Sigma - $ matrix of eigenvalues, sorted by value, in ascending order. I think then I get intuition of this equation. The biggest eigenvalues from $\Sigma^{-k}$ have more contribute at non-diagonal elements, so they decreasing as the degree increases.

Comment: you need $\Sigma$ to have like exponentially decreasing elements on the diagonal. Then you can write it elementwise and prove it swiftly

Comment: To get the right font and spacing for an operator like $\operatorname{diag}$, use `\operatorname{diag}`.

Comment: This cannot be true. Taking the factors of $\Sigma$ to the right-hand side yields a product of diagonal matrices, which is itself diagonal, so $L$ would have to be diagonal.

Comment: I don't know how can I refute your statement, but I've experimented with different matrixes in numpy and it was true.  I know it's weak argument, but I'm thinking that wiki's prove can't be wrong...